# В spring security не работает logout, если включил remember-me

Tags: java, spring-security

Привет всем. 
Прикрутил remember-me, если галочку (remember-me) не ставить, то нормально работает.

Если поставить галочку (remember-me) и потом перейти на страницу logout, система выкидывает на страницу авторизации, но если зайти на любую закрытую страницу, то я захожу, как авторизированный пользователь, т.е. выхода фактически не было и браузер будет меня помнить, пока не закончится срок cookies.

В настройках прописывал, чтобы удалять "JSESSIONID" и "remember-me", но результата не принесло. Как нужно описать, чтобы выход происходил?

Настройки Security

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDetailsService")
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void registerGlobalAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(getShaPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/static/**", "/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().permitAll().and();

        http.formLogin().loginPage("/login").usernameParameter("login")
                .passwordParameter("password").and().rememberMe().rememberMeParameter("remember-me")
                .tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository()).tokenValiditySeconds(86400).and()
                .csrf().and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");

        http.logout().permitAll().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true).deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");

        /* http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403"); */
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository()
    {
        JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl tokenRepositoryImpl = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
        tokenRepositoryImpl.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return tokenRepositoryImpl;
    }

    @Bean
    public ShaPasswordEncoder getShaPasswordEncoder()
    {
        return new ShaPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Сервис

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService
{
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login) throws UsernameNotFoundException
    {
        User user = userService.getUser(login);
        if (user == null)
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found");
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getLogin(),
                user.getPassword(), true, true, true, true, getGrantedAuthorities(user));
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(User user)
    {
        Set<UserRole> userRols = user.getRols();
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        for (UserRole userRole : userRols)
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + userRole.getRole()));
        return authorities;
    }
}
```

Часть контроллера

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginPage()
    {
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String logoutPage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (auth != null)
            new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, auth);
        return "redirect:/login?logout";
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Единственное, что сработало, так в контроллере на logout дописать следующий код перед return. Тогда выход работает

```
        for (Cookie cookie : request.getCookies())
        {
            System.out.println(cookie.getName());
            if (cookie.getName().equals("remember-me")) {
                cookie.setMaxAge(0);
                response.addCookie(cookie);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

В `AbstractRememberMeServices` описана константа `SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE_KEY = "remember-me"`

Это имя cookie в которой сохраняется remember-me токен.
Если вы не изменяли его, очистка должна помочь.

правильно будет так

```
.deleteCookies(AbstractRememberMeServices.SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE_KEY)
```

Comment: Не помогло, так же пробовал в самом начале, только не через константу "AbstractRememberMeServices.SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE_KEY", а на прямую "remember-me"

Comment: Тут еще есть фитча. На стороне клиента предполагается, что вы тут же зайдете под другим пользователем и очистка клиентской куки не производится. Кука rememder-me остается до закрытия браузера. Нужно так же чистить javascript на странице logout. Проверьте остается ли кука после того как вы закроете браузер и откроете по новой.

Comment: Если после выхода сразу же попробовать залогиниться, даже неправильно, то выход происходил. В барузере кука rememder-me остаётся после закрытия. Дополню тогда ещё на стороне клиента очистку javascript